# Ionic Capacitor Camera, generate full quality image and display it without generating Base64 and DataUri

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

In my Ionic Project, I am using Capacitor for deployment in mobile platforms.

For capturing an image from device, I am using Capacitor Camera which helps me to get the image in three formats.
1. Base64.
2. DataUrl.
3. FileUri.

```
onCaptureImage() {
    if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Camera')) {
      this._sharedService.showToastMessage(
        'Unable To Open Camera', 1000);
      return;
    }
    Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 60,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt,
      correctOrientation: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl
    })
      .then(image => {
        const blobImg = this._sharedService.dataURItoBlob(image.dataUrl);
        this.myfiles.push(blobImg);
        this.urls.push(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image.dataUrl));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return false;
      });
  }
```

From this `DataUrl` I am using to display the image and for uploading this image, I am converting it into `Blob` and then sending it through `FormData`.

Right now the quality is 60, I want the quality as 100. But it hangs the device when we generate `DataUrl` out of 100 quality image.

I just want to know that is there any way that we can generate `FileUri` with having quality 100 and also can preview the image without generating `Base64` or `DataUrl` out of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of the huge base64 string is what hangs the app.
Look at this solution...

Use the **camera settings** as below:

```
Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 100,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
    source: CameraSource.Prompt
  }).then((image) => {
//imgSrc is passed to src of img tag
imgSrc = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image && (image.webPath));

// image.path is what you will have to send to the uploadPhoto method as uripath
      });
```

The Uri format will give you the local file path which can be easily passed to the filetransfer plugin... ***image.path*** is the local file path returned by the camera..

For transferring the file to a server, you will need the cordova file-transfer plugin..the code will look like this..

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer)

uploadPhoto(fileName:string, uripath:string):Promise<any>{
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  const options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'file',
    fileName: fileName,
    mimeType: 'image/jpg',
    chunkedMode: false,
    params: {
      //any params that you want to attach for the server to use
    },
    headers: {
      //any specific headers go here
    }
  };
  fileTransfer.upload(uripath, <APIEndpointURL>, options)
    .then((result) => {
      // success
    resolve(result);
    }, (err) => {
      // error
      reject(err);
    });
});
}
```

With this your server will definitely receive the file, irrespective of image quality.. i have used this method on both node.js and php servers.

Comment: A little bit off topic but can anyone tell me if it is possible to get the full camera resolution when taking a photo using .getPhoto() without having to through any prompt?